# SQL Server: Use multiple aggregate/analytic functions with same OVER clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

The following SQL Server query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NodeID, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Timestamp), 0) as dt_hour
,AVG(Availability)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY NodeID, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Timestamp), 0)) AS avg  
,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Availability)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY NodeID, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Timestamp), 0)) AS perc90  
,MAX(Availability)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY NodeID, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Timestamp), 0)) AS max  
FROM InterfaceAvailability_CS_Detail_hist
order by NodeID, dt_hour;
```

takes about 3 times as long to run as this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NodeID, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Timestamp), 0) as dt_hour
,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Availability)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY NodeID, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Timestamp), 0)) AS perc90  
FROM InterfaceAvailability_CS_Detail_hist
order by NodeID, dt_hour;
```

I suspect it's redundantly partioning for each aggregation (`AVG`, `PERCENTILE_CONT`, `MAX`). Is there a way to write the `OVER` clause only once and apply it to each aggregation?

Comment: Functions using an `OVER` clause aren't aggregation functions...

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and indexes (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito), the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format and the current plans for your queries.

Comment: "The OVER clause may follow all aggregate functions" - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql)

Comment: @MarkPundurs, Using redundant `PARTITION BY` clauses doesn't necessarily result in redundant work being performed.  Can you share your query plan?

Comment: It's almost certainly the `DISTINCT` that is causing you problems. Why is it there in the first place, by the looks of things you really want a `GROUP BY` with normal aggregation. The exact same `PARTITION BY` multiple times will almost certainly *not* calculate the partition multiple times, only the actual function will be

Comment: Can I do PERCENTILE_CONT with normal aggregation? I didn't see that in the Oracle docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the query plan it is hard to tell what's going on, but my guess is that by using a scalar function in the *parititon by* clause you're limiting what sql server can do to optimize the query.

I experimented with a similar query and by using a CTE to generate values for the *dt_hour* column I was able to produce a plan that had less Sort, Nested Loops and Stream Aggregate operations.  Since I don't know the cost of these operations in your original query, I don't know if this will produce a better result, as just seeing less stuff in the plan doesn't necessarily mean improvement.

```
WITH processed AS (
    SELECT *, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Timestamp), 0) as dt_hour
    FROM InterfaceAvailability_CS_Detail_hist
)
SELECT DISTINCT NodeID, dt_hour
,AVG(Availability)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY NodeID, dt_hour) AS avg  
,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Availability)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY NodeID, dt_hour) AS perc90  
,MAX(Availability)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY NodeID, dt_hour) AS max  
FROM processed
order by NodeID, dt_hour;
```